# how to find taylor polynomial for $f(x)=x^{10}/(1-x)$

Tags: calculus

first, I tried to find its derivatives for the function, and plugin $0$, but i got $0$ for the first $3$ derivatives, i dont know if i should keep going or i have some errors! is there other ways to find this taylor polynomial other than taking derivatives, and i looked up the taylor polynomial for my function and $f(x)=1/(1-x)$ and found the answers have the same pattern. for my function, the taylor polynomial starts with $x^{10}$, so that means first $9$ derivatives are all equal to $0$, and i assume there is another way to find this taylor polynomial.

Comment: Keep taking derivatives. And you didn't get "0" unless you're looking for a Maclaurin series.

Comment: @Shahar "Keep taking derivatives" is a pretty bad advice for this example.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $f(x) = \dfrac{x^{10}}{1-x}=-\dfrac{1-x^{10}}{1-x}+\dfrac{1}{1-x}=-1-x-x^2-\cdots -x^{9}+(1+x+x^2+\cdots)= \displaystyle \sum_{k=10}^\infty x^k$

Answer (score 0):

you can use the geometric series 
$$y=x^{10}(1+x+x^2+x^3+....x^n)$$

Answer (score 0):

it is much easier to multiply  the geometric series for $$\frac1 {1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots$$ by $x^{10}$ to get $$ \frac{x^{10}} {1-x} = x^{10} + x^{11} + x^{12} + x^{13} + \cdots $$